# C# Winforms Cefsharp cache path is to big

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm using this code to Init a `CefSharp` browser with a specific cache path(i have a specific cache path because my app use a lot of login options):

```
browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("");

var requestContextSettings = new RequestContextSettings { CachePath = UsersManager.GetFullCachePath(userName) };
browser.RequestContext = new RequestContext(requestContextSettings, new CustomRequestContextHandler());

browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
browser.FrameLoadEnd += webViewFrameLoadEnd;
browser.LoadError += getFromBrowser_LoadError;

BrowserPanel.Controls.Add(browser);
```

The issue here is that for every user the cache folder is taking something like 300 MB, There is an option to make a limitation on this folder? I only need it to save the cookies for the logins and O think it saves a lot of information that I don't need.

Comment: There are no options for cache size that I'm aware of. You can possibly leave the CachePath blank and use an in memory cache and specify a cookie manager using the request context handler.

Comment: Actually looks like Chromium does have https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disk-cache-size no idea if it works in CEF,  you'll have to try it. Size is in bytes

Comment: @amaitland Thanks! if i use cookie manager, can i save it for next app run? For example login to a website, close the app and reopen it, the last session will be saved?

Comment: In theory, I've not actually tried that exact scenario, try it and find out.

Comment: @amaitland If i will disable images download will this decrease the cache directory?

Comment: Never tried. Give it a go and find out.